# Hover over div, changes section background image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the features section:`<section id="features">` @ https://dreem.com/en/

Basically, I'd like to change the background images and text and iconography.

I've been playing around with it here: https://codepen.io/JordiUp/pen/XZJdQO

But I haven't figured out how to the get the hove transitions working.

Am I able to achive this effect within just a section using HTML and CSS, or am i missing something and need Javascript.

First time posting, Huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you, Please refer this link

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-image-swap-on-hover